# Regex to detect the colon and sides of it?

Tags: php, regex

First see my string please:

```
$a = "[ child : parent ]";
```

How can I detect that the pattern is:

```
 [(optional space)word or character(optional space) : (optional space)word or character(optional space)]
```

Comment: `word or character` - what do you mean exactly? Is `*@#$+={}[];'/.,` consider "word or character"?

Comment: What kind of chars can word contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample text I'd say you mean a *human word* and not `\w` *regex word*

```
preg_match('/\[ ?([a-z]+) ?: ?([a-z]+) ?\]/i', $a, $matches);
```

Explained demo: http://regex101.com/r/hB2oV9

`$matches` will save both values, test with `var_dump($matches);`

Answer (score 2):

You can catch this as follows in PHP:

Your regular expression is `/\[ *\w+ *: *\w+ *]/`

You would write code that would look like this to see if it matched.

```
if (preg_match('/regex/', $string)) {
    // do things
}
```

**Explanation of the Regular Expression**

- There is a backslash (`\`) before the open bracket because
  `[` has special meaning in regular expressions. The backslash
  prevents its special meaning from being used.
- The asterisk (`*`) matches 0 or more of the previous character expression. In this
  case, it matches 0 or more spaces. If you instead used the
  expression `\s*`, it would match 0 or more white-space characters
  (space, tab, line break). Finally, if you wanted it to match 0 or 1
  of the previous character, you would use `?` instead of `*`.
- The plus (`+`) matches 1 or more of the previous character expression. The `\w` character expression matches a letter, digit, or underscore. If you don't want underscores to match, you should instead use a character class. For example, you could use `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

You can find more information on regular expressions at http://www.regular-expressions.info and http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on the php-specific version of regex, but this should work:

```
\[ ?\w+ ? :  ?\w+ ?\]
```

[Here](http://regex.powertoy.org/) is a site that I've used in the past to find regular expressions for my needed patterns.

Answer (score 1):

use this regex  `\[\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*\]`

Comment: You know that `\s` also include new line character and the likes, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it like this

`preg_match('/^\[\s?\w+\s+:\s+\w+\s?\]$/', $string)`

Comment: `\s+` doesn't match an *optional* space. Instead, it matches one or more spaces.

Comment: @corvec That's because he has an optional space followed by a literal space so I assumed 1 or more.

Comment: Ah, I suppose that interpretation makes sense.